# Creación de hilo a partir de hilo principal

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas Estoy probando el tema de los hilos en java y me gustaría conseguir que un hilo principal creara un vector de números aleatorios y que este creara un segundo hilo que fuera el que sumara los números creados en el vector del hilo principal.

Tengo este código

```
public class Principal {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Proceso hilo1 = new Proceso("Hilo 1");
        Proceso hilo2 = new Proceso("Hilo 2");
        hilo1.setMensaje("Este es el mensaje del hilo 1");
        hilo2.setMensaje("Mensaje hilo 2");
        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
    }
}

public class Proceso extends Thread {
    String nombre;

    public Proceso(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            System.out.println(nombre);
        }
        System.out.println("Termina thread " + this.getName());
    }

    public void setMensaje(String msj) {
        this.nombre = msj;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Así como lo estás planteando se ve un poco complicado puesto que el hilo2 debería esperar a que el hilo1 cree un array para luego sumarlo. Es más sencillo crear el array desde el hilo1 y una vez rellenado, crear desde ese mismo hilo el hilo2 y pasarle el vector, así seguro que siguen un orden correcto.

Comment: ¿ Como podría implementarlo para que primero creara el array de números aleatorios y luego el hilo segundo los sumara?